# Compare two distributions for the same entities

Tags: statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'd like to compare two distributions of measurements for the same entities, to determine the degree to which the two distributions measure the same underlying phenomenon. For example, I'd like to compare countries in the [Human Development Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Development_Index) to the same countries in the [OECD Better Life Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OECD_Better_Life_Index) to determine the degree to which the two indices measure the same thing.

I know that if I were comparing samples to see whether they came from the same population, I'd use, for example, the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test). In my case, though, I have additional information: the entity (country) in each distribution (index). Which test should I use that accounts for this additional information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In psychometrics, the degree of agreement between two tests that are supposed to measure the same thing is called convergent validity. Agreement can be measured with Pearson correlation, if you think there's a linear relationship between the scores on the two measures, or with Spearman or Kendall correlation, if you just think there's a monotonic relationship. In this case the assumption of a linear relationship seems very unrealistic, because the two indices use different units that have no defined conversion factor, so I would recommend Spearman or Kendall.

Comment: Thank you! I'd not thought of Pearson/Spearman/Kendal. Appreciate you noting the concept, too, (convergent validity) as this gives me something to explore further.